# How to wait for multiple actions finished in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want to dispatch multiple actions and then I get the result to dispatch another action. the code looks like this

```
// schemaNames is an array
// submit is an action creator for redux form.
schemaNames.forEach(schemaName => submit(schemaName));
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.vals));

// in each form. I set the onsubmit like this:
<MyForm
  onSubmit={value => this.vals[schemaName] = value}
/>
```

After I dispatch all the submit actions, the vals should be a object which contains multiple properties. However, I found that it doesn't.

I tried with another solution. I just let console.log wait for a second like this.

```
// even though I want to 0 second, I can get the result!
setTimeOut(() => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.vals));
}, 0);
```

That is quite bizarre. I tried with promise, and it doesn't work. maybe I write it wrong. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using something like `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`? In any case, maybe you could change your action so that it takes an array of schema names instead of a single one, and move the `forEach` statement inside the action?

Comment: @MattHolland I am using the redux observable, the problem is that the submit action is provided by redux-form. I cannot change it.